# How do you make a class flatMappable?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm finding myself wanting to write this:

```
def allAsAndFs(node: Node): PairOfSeqs[Action, Factor] =
  node.regularNames.flatMap { name => regularAsAndFs(name) } ++
  node.specialNames.flatMap { name => specialAsAndFs(name) }
```

where:

```
def regularNames: Seq[String]
def specialNames: Seq[String]

def regularAsAndFs(name: String): PairOfSeqs[Action, Factor]
def specialAsAndFs(name: String): PairOfSeqs[Action, Factor]
```

and:

```
class PairOfSeqs[A, B](as: Seq[A], bs: Seq[B]) {
  def ++(that: PairOfSeqs[A, B]): PairOfSeqs[A, B] =
    PairOfSeqs(as ++ that.as, bs ++ that.bs)
  . . .
}
```

What do I need to do to make `flatMap` coalesce the `PairsOfSeqs` by
calling the appropriate `++` method?

It looks like `PairOfSeqs` should extend `GenTraversableOnce`, but
`GenTraversableOnce` has a rather astonishing 47 abstract methods to override.

What's the idiomatic, Scalastic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a somewhat nonstandard idea of `flatMap`.  The normal type signature is

```
class C[A] {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => C[B]): C[B] = ???
}
```

But you want (something akin to--this will not compile):

```
  def foo[D <: { def ++(d: D): D }](f: A => D): D
```

which is much more like `fold` than `flatMap`.

One possibility is to make `PairOfSeqs` a full-fledged collection.  That's going to be tough because the types really don't line up that well, and because extending collections is difficult.  (The reward/effort ratio can be good because even though the effort is large the reward is *huge*, if you really need it.)

Perhaps the best possibility is just to have an extension method on `Seq`.

```
case class PairOfSeqs[A, B](as: Seq[A], bs: Seq[B]) {
  def ++(that: PairOfSeqs[A, B]): PairOfSeqs[A,B] =
    PairOfSeqs(as ++ that.as, bs ++ that.bs)
}

implicit class SeqCanPairMap[A](val underlying: Seq[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def flatPair[B,C](f: A => PairOfSeqs[B,C]): PairOfSeqs[B,C] = {
    val ps = underlying.map(f)
    PairOfSeqs(ps.map(_.as).fold(Seq[B]())(_ ++ _), ps.map(_.bs).fold(Seq[C]())(_ ++ _))
  }
}

Seq("fish", "fowl").flatPair(s => new PairOfSeqs(s.map(_.toChar), s.map(_.toInt)))
```

There are a variety of other options (e.g. define a more conventional `flatMap` on `PairOfSeqs`, and a conversion from regular seqs to a PairOfSeqs with an empty second slot), but this probably covers your use case well enough.

Finally, to make a class `flatMappable` in general, all you have to do is define `flatMap`.  In particular, for-comprehensions can then use it.  (But you'll need a `map` also or it won't be useful for for-comprehensions.)

Comment: I thought adding a `flatMap` method to `PairOfSeqs` wouldn't work, because `Seq.flatMap` actually gets called. `Seq.flatMap` can coalesce ("flatten") `List`s, `Option`s, `Set`s, and other things correctly. I want to know how to make it coalesce `PairsOfSeqs` correctly. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about `flatMap`? (I'm still digesting `SeqPairCanMap`...)

Comment: @BenKovitz - `flatMap` actually calls builders obtained from an implicit `CanBuildFrom`.  But I think what you're asking is whether you can get an _implicit_ conversion from `Seq` to `PairOfSeqs` when you use `flatMap`.  There, the answer is no.

Comment: OK, now I think I see my confusion, which is well explained by the type signatures at the top of your answer. I had forgotten that `Seq.flatMap` returns a `Seq`, `Set.flatMap` returns a `Set`, etc., just not necessarily with the same type parameters. I was thinking that `flatMap(f)` would return a value with the same type that `f` returns (which I guess it does, when used normally). Thanks!

Comment: And now I understand `SeqCanPairMap`. Yup, what I'm really trying to do is an implicit fold. Thanks again; that was some fast enlightenment.